# Where can I find Galois original paper?

Tags: soft-question

As we all know Galois is an ultimate math prodigy. At age 17 or 18 he published a paper which we now know as Galois theory. I want to just see how he thought mathematics by seeing his original paper(of-course translated in english).

Thanks!

Comment: Some information available [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98456/original-works-of-great-mathematician-%C3%89variste-galois)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know a few of his papers appear (translated) in a book Hawking edited, [*God Created the Integers*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0762430044). I'm sure his papers can be obtained elsewhere, probably for free even. The three in the book are

- *On the conditions  that an equation be soluble by radicals*,
- *On the primitive equations which are soluble by radicals*, and
- *On Groups and Equations and Abelian Integrals*

The upside to Hawking's book (whose title is part of a quote by [Kronecker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopold_Kronecker), by the way) is that you get *much* more than just Galois's three papers. There are original works of Euclid, Archimedes, Descartes, Riemann, Cantor, Dedekind, and quite a few more (ironically, no Kronecker from what I can see!). The full table of contents can be viewed [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=eU_RzM7OoI4C&pg=PR9&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false).

I can't help but mention that the book is currently shockingly cheap, for 1300+ pages!

Answer (score 7):

The best Galois full edition you will ever find is found here:
https://uberty.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Peter_M._Neumann_The_Mathematical_Writings.pdf

Answer (score 3):

A google search for his 1897 collected works, [**Oeuvres mathematiques d'Évariste Galois**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Oeuvres+math%C3%A9matiques+d%27Evariste+Galois%22), turns up quite a few freely available copies:

[copy at Internet Archivev](https://archive.org/details/uvresmathmatiqu00frangoog)

[copy at Christophe Clanet's web pages](https://www.irphe.fr/~clanet/otherpaperfile/articles/Galois/)

[copy at google-books](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZOkGAAAAYAAJ)

[copies at Project Gutenberg](http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/gutbook/lookup?num=40213)

[Gallica's copy of some work published in 1846 in Liouville's Journal](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k290623/)

Answer (score 2):

[Oeuvres mathématiques d'Évariste Galois by Évariste Galois](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/40213/40213-pdf.pdf?session_id=cacdcb683f105e0d90ea81986953ab5c38da2848) is the PDF article in French about some of his published works.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Editions Jacques Gabay](http://www.gabay-editeur.com/epages/300555.sf/fr_FR/?ObjectID=9304205&ViewAction=FacetedSearchProducts&SearchString=galois&=). They are providing reprints of old scientific books. They are in French, but not the formulas.

Answer (score 1):

[Link irphe](https://www.irphe.fr/~clanet/otherpaperfile/articles/Galois/N0029062_PDF_1_84.pdf)

[Link Archive](https://archive.org/search.php?query=%28%28subject%3A%22Galois%2C%20%C3%89variste%22%20OR%20subject%3A%22%C3%89variste%20Galois%22%20OR%20creator%3A%22Galois%2C%20%C3%89variste%22%20OR%20creator%3A%22%C3%89variste%20Galois%22%20OR%20creator%3A%22Galois%2C%20%C3%89.%22%20OR%20title%3A%22%C3%89variste%20Galois%22%20OR%20description%3A%22Galois%2C%20%C3%89variste%22%20OR%20description%3A%22%C3%89variste%20Galois%22%29%20OR%20%28%221811-1832%22%20AND%20Galois%29%29%20AND%20%28-mediatype:software%29)

[Link Gutemberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/40213)